# Is there anything insecure about opening port 80 just to redirect?

Tags: ubuntu, https, http, port-forwarding

Its a pretty simple question, is there any real network insecurity to opening up port 80 just so I can redirect them to ssl? Currently you have to type https:// just to access one of the sites. Is there anything bad with opening port 80 just to automatically redirect to the same url on port 443?

Comment: Port 80 needs to be reachable that the redirection works. But what is the Question and the related Business Issue? OR is this question Privat related and in this case i please you to move your Question to superuser.com

Comment: @djdomi this doesn't answer my question, I know 80 has to be reachable, just wondering the security issues. Also, how do I move it to superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no issue with opening port 80. The insecurities with opening ports on a firewall is caused by allowing a service to be accessed by the public which shouldn't be public. Opening port 80 to redirect to port 443 is completely fine.